# React/html: Disable autofocus on page render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, focus, textarea

I have some buttons, which open a textarea field when clicked, and the area needs to have focus. The problem i have, is when i render the page, and one of the focusable texareas is already selected, it will automatically scroll to the bottom of the page to target the focused element.

How would i disable this automatic focus on first render?

Autofocus is on this textarea field:

```
<textarea
      type="textarea"
      className={`ostalo-txt ${ isOstalo ? 'left-radius-0' : 'left-radius-0 ostalo-quantity'} ${ item.name === "Ostalo" ? 'ostalo-txt-area' : ''}`}
      name={`ostaloVsadek`}
      onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e, item)}
      value={textAreaValue(item).toString()}
      data-idx={idx}
      disabled={!editable}
      autoFocus
/>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of how you *open* the `textarea`

Comment: Add a local state to that component and  set it default as false, and check like `autoFocus={isFirstRender && isNewElement ? true : false }` then manage isFirstRender wherever you want to set.

Comment: @Aslamkhan 
i set up a state that tracks first render and gave the autofocus the condition you wrote. it works. thank you!